# Mandrill - Inbound Email processing route not working with SSL

Tags: email, ssl, protocols, mandrill

We're using Mandrill to send emails and also to receive email that we parse. When setting up the inbound processing route and using an HTTP route, everything works fine. When we try to put a route using HTTPS we get the following error message:

> HEAD to https://example.com/api/v1/messages/ failed: Unknown SSL
>   protocol error in connection to example.com:443

Is there a specific SSL protocol that is required for Mandrill?

Answer (score 1):

We just figured it out. We did have TLSv1.2 enabled already but looks like it requires a lower version. We enabled TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](http://blog.mandrill.com/poodle-sslv3-update.html), SSLv3 is of course not supported, but most versions of TLS should work. Seeing support for up to TLSv1.2 in my own tests.

Comment: Yes we had TLSv1.2 already enabled. It worked when we enabled lower TLS versions.